# javascript array not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my html strcture

```
<div class="parent">
    <input class="child1" value="1">
    <input class="child2" value="2">
    <input class="child3" value="3">

</div>
```

i need to make a javascript array

**combined_array={child1:"1", child2:"2", child3:"3"};**

for this i write the following code . But it is not correct . Please help to find out error

```
$('.parent').children('input').each(function () {
                              var c_class=$(this).attr("class");
                              var c_value=$(this).val();
                              var combined_array={c_class:c_value};
                          });

                       alert(combined_array);
```

Comment: What is your result?

Comment: That's an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals) and not an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Array_literals)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are re-initializing the `combined_array` variable on each iteration so the result would be an object containing single property.

Instead initialize object outside and define property within the [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method callback.

```js
var combined = {};
$('.parent').children('input').each(function() {
  var c_class = $(this).attr("class");
  var c_value = $(this).val();
  combined[c_class] = c_value;
});

console.log(combined);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <input class="child1" value="1">
  <input class="child2" value="2">
  <input class="child3" value="3">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var combined_array={};
$('.parent').children('input').each(function () {
       combined_array[$(this).attr("class")]=$(this).val();
});
console.log(combined_array);
//alert(combined_array);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <input class="child1" value="1">
    <input class="child2" value="2">
    <input class="child3" value="3">
</div>
```